# None value not supported , Keras LSTM fit

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Dear all I am using Keras 2.3.1 and Tensorflow 2.0.0 to run the following code:

```
def lstm_nn_model(
        trainings_data: np.array,
        prediction_data: np.array,
        target_train: np.array,
        learning_rate: float = 0.001,
        lstm_units: int = 100,
        batch_size: int = 72,
        epochs: int = 1000,
        seq_len: float = 4):
    # LSTM part
    lstm_input = Input(batch_shape=trainings_data.shape, dtype='float32',
                       name='lstm_input')
    lstm_out = LSTM(lstm_units, return_sequences=False)(lstm_input)
    # Output
    output = Dense(1, name='output')(lstm_out)

    # compile model
    adam_opt = Adam(lr=learning_rate, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None,
                    decay=0.0, amsgrad=False)
    lstm_model = Model(inputs=lstm_input, outputs=output)
    lstm_model.compile(
        optimizer=adam_opt, loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy']
    )
    # Train
    lstm_model.fit(
        x=trainings_data ,
        y=target_train,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        epochs=epochs,
        verbose=2
    )
    return lstm_model.predict(prediction_data)
```

My Data has no NaN's or Nulls. You can download the data I use her https://share.nuclino.com/p/shared-c2ReL9zRLknyKuNPlEmrtg. There are pickled numpy arrays (numpy version 1.17.1). 
Actually I do not know why this happens and the similar answers were not helpful. Please let me know If you need help to reproduce the error. Thanks in advance.

The complete error message:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-2930b20ab5e4> in <module>()
      2 target_train_data = target_train[3:]
      3 pred_data = pre_process_lstm_predictors(prediction_data, 3)
----> 4 pred_lstm = lstm_nn_model(train_data, pred_data, target_train_data)

~/Desktop/python_projects/meteoIntelligence-projects/src/dataScience/modellingServices.py in lstm_nn_model(trainings_data, prediction_data, target_train, learning_rate, lstm_units, batch_size, epochs, seq_len)
    267         batch_size=batch_size,
    268         epochs=epochs,
--> 269         verbose=2
    270     )
    271     return lstm_model.predict(prediction_data)

~/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
   1211         else:
   1212             fit_inputs = x + y + sample_weights
-> 1213         self._make_train_function()
   1214         fit_function = self.train_function
   1215 

~/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _make_train_function(self)
    314                     training_updates = self.optimizer.get_updates(
    315                         params=self._collected_trainable_weights,
--> 316                         loss=self.total_loss)
    317                 updates = self.updates + training_updates
    318 

~/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name + '` call to the ' +
     90                               'Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

~/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in symbolic_fn_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     73         if _SYMBOLIC_SCOPE.value:
     74             with get_graph().as_default():
---> 75                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
     76         else:
     77             return func(*args, **kwargs)

~/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/optimizers.py in get_updates(self, loss, params)
    541                 self.updates.append(K.update(vhat, vhat_t))
    542             else:
--> 543                 p_t = p - lr_t * m_t / (K.sqrt(v_t) + self.epsilon)
    544 
    545             self.updates.append(K.update(m, m_t))

~/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/math_ops.py in binary_op_wrapper(x, y)
    901         try:
    902           y = ops.convert_to_tensor_v2(
--> 903               y, dtype_hint=x.dtype.base_dtype, name="y")
    904         except TypeError:
    905           # If the RHS is not a tensor, it might be a tensor aware object

~/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in convert_to_tensor_v2(value, dtype, dtype_hint, name)
   1240       name=name,
   1241       preferred_dtype=dtype_hint,
-> 1242       as_ref=False)
   1243 
   1244 

~/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in internal_convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, ctx, accept_composite_tensors)
   1294 
   1295     if ret is None:
-> 1296       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
   1297 
   1298     if ret is NotImplemented:

~/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/constant_op.py in _constant_tensor_conversion_function(v, dtype, name, as_ref)
    284                                          as_ref=False):
    285   _ = as_ref
--> 286   return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
    287 
    288 

~/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/constant_op.py in constant(value, dtype, shape, name)
    225   """
    226   return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,
--> 227                         allow_broadcast=True)
    228 
    229 

~/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/constant_op.py in _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape, allow_broadcast)
    263       tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(
    264           value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape,
--> 265           allow_broadcast=allow_broadcast))
    266   dtype_value = attr_value_pb2.AttrValue(type=tensor_value.tensor.dtype)
    267   const_tensor = g.create_op(

~/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/tensor_util.py in make_tensor_proto(values, dtype, shape, verify_shape, allow_broadcast)
    435   else:
    436     if values is None:
--> 437       raise ValueError("None values not supported.")
    438     # if dtype is provided, forces numpy array to be the type
    439     # provided if possible.
```

Answer (score 3):

Quite simple, you cannot set `epsilon=None` in `Adam`. It needs to be a number (usually a small number > 0). Just use `adam_opt = Adam(lr=learning_rate)`, the rest is at default values anyway.